# A proper way to handling a failure in Airflow task

Tags: airflow

Is there any difference between the following ways for handling Airflow tasks failure?

First way -

```
def handle_failure(**kwargs):
    do_something(kwargs)

def on_failure_callback(context):
    set_train_status_failed = PythonOperator(
        task_id="handle_failure",
        provide_context=True,
        queue="master",
        python_callable=handle_failure)

    return set_train_status_failed.execute(context=context)
```

Second way -

```
def on_failure_callback(context):
        do_something(context)
```

As I understand and correct me please if I'm wrong, context and kwargs are the same dictionaries?
I ask because I see examples for both of the ways and I don't understand what is the difference in case the first one uses PythonOperator.

Comment: As per the official documentation of airflow, context dictionary is passed to the failure callback. This might help https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/index.html#airflow.models.Base

Comment: And what is the difference between both ways to handle the failure, that I mention above? @Zohair

Comment: I see no difference in the result assuming no syntax failures, although I might add, I have never used an Operator as part of callbacks - the second approach is much cleaner and readable